# CodeIgniter FileUpload Not Allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm setting up an upload form in CodeIgniter. I've setup the allowed_types parameter to:

```
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
```

And added the following line to config/mimes.php:

```
'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel'),
'xlsx'  =>  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
```

However, despite the file I'm trying to upload being an xlsx file CI is still telling me the filetype isn't allowed. Any thoughts?

```
  public function do_upload() {

    // Change this if you change the upload directory
    $upload_path = "/webusers/ad6vcf/public_html/funding_manager/application/uploads";

    $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;

    //At some point will add support for csv
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';

    //Max 5000kb please
    $config['max_size'] = '5000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);


    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->upload($error);
    } else {

        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        bulk_insert($upload_path . $upload_data['file_name']);

    }

}
```

Comment: why are you commenting this line  //$config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';

Comment: That was a mistake, uncommented it now but still getting the same error

Comment: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Try this as mime type for xlsx

Comment: @VaisakhPc done, I've updaed my question with new code, still not working :(

Comment: 'xlsx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/zip').

Comment: add this and check 'xlsx'=>array('application/vnd.ms-excel','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','appli‌​cation/zip')

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

`$this->load->library('upload', $config);
 $this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: first try **xls** and try **xlxs** r u getting error on both ?

Comment: Now put 'xlsx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),

for XLXS then try

Comment: Still same error. The file I am trying to upload: 01\usrt11\ROF\max\ManW7\Desktop\universities hr contact.xlsx

Comment: check what this is the type on $_FILES['input_file_name']['type'] and add that in mime.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66260/discussion-between-rana-soyab-and-max0005).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('put the name of the input field here'))
```